# Use deriver in Drupal Migration yml

Tags: migrations, 9, plugins

I am trying to use the deriver key in a migration yml to have dynamically build migrations for each bundle of an Entity Type (Drupal 9).

I read [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/writing-migrations-for-contributed-and-custom-modules#s-advanced-example-node-migration-uses-deriver-class-to-dynamically-build-migrations-for-each-content-type) and I am trying to use the deriver key to point to a Deriver class in my migration. However it seems that the deriver key is just ignored.

Is there something else that I need to do beside using the deriver key and create a deriver class that inherits from Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase?

This is the migration yml:

```
id: person_roles
label: Import 
deriver: Drupal\my_module\PersonRoleImportDeriver
migration_group: my_group
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls: public://this.xml
  fields:
    -
      name: position_name
      label: person role name
      selector: funktion
  ids:
    position_name:
      type: string
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:my_entity'
process:
  name:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: position_name
      message: 'Empty source person role'
    -
      plugin: make_unique_entity_field
      entity_type: my_entity
      migrated: true
      field: name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a plugin, so you need to respect the plugin directory structure and namespace.

Your class should be in `my_module/src/Plugin/migrate` and have the namespace `Drupal\my_module\Plugin\migrate`.

Comment: Hm, I think a Deriver is not a plugin? It has no annotation though. Anyway, if I put the Deriver in the plugin folder it still seems not get called.

Comment: So your deriver class implements getDerivativeDefinitions() and that method never gets called?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Not sure why that would be, I use the same pattern. Does your class include the MigrationDeriverTrait?

Comment: it seems its about where the config yml for the migration lives. If it lives in config/install folder the deriver will not get caught, but if it lives in the migrations folder it will work. The Deriver class itself could live anywhere in the namespace. I am just currently understanding the difference between config/install and migrations in that case.

Comment: Ah interesting, we switched to using the migrations directory fairly early on.